# restricting to only alpha letters on django forms based on widget-tweaks

Tags: django, orm

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validate(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        var regex = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
        var isValid = regex.test(String.fromCharCode(keyCode));
        return isValid;
    }
</script>
```

Then the call:

```
{% render_field form_built_properties.building_material|attr:"onkeypress(Validate)" class="form-control" %}

I tried this alone, doesn't work either:
{% render_field form_built_properties.building_material|attr:'onkeydown="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)"' 
TRY VERSION 2:

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function () {
  $('#material').keydown(function (e) {
      if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
          e.preventDefault();
      } else {
          var key = e.keyCode;
          if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
              e.preventDefault();
          }
      }
  });
});
});
</script>
```

AND

```
{% render_field form_built_properties.building_material|attr:'id:"material"' class="form-control" %}
```

doesn't work either. I can still enter numbers in the text field

TRIAL 3: (doesn't work either) I tried to restrict it in the forms.py file

```
class Meta:
        model = BuiltProperties
        building_material = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autocomplete': 'off', 'pattern': '[A-Za-z]+',
                   'title': 'Enter Characters Only '}))
        fields = ['description', 'building_material']
```

TRIAL 4:
This worked, one liner:

```
{% render_field form_built_properties.building_material|attr:"pattern=[A-Za-z]+"  class="form-control" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be more scalable and elegant way to do this

make a jquery function for restricting non aplha character, with a class selector.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.alpha_only').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
})
});
</script>
```

Then add this class to wherever you want to apply restriction via django forms

```
class Meta:
        model = BuiltProperties
        building_material = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control alpha_only', 'autocomplete': 'off', 'pattern': '[A-Za-z]+',
                   'title': 'Enter Characters Only '}))
        fields = ['description', 'building_material']
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked  `{% render_field form_built_properties.building_material|attr:"pattern=[A-Za-z]+"  class="form-control" %}`

As simple as that.
With regards to the answer provided by a contributor, I wonder if you had a chance to read my post because what you provide is a copycat of what I wrote, which I had myself found on the net.